# how to escape plus sign in lucene library 4.1.0

Tags: java, sql, lucene

the query i have is `cs_contents:(canal+) OR cs_docs:(canal+) OR cs_annots:(canal+)`

when is passed in `lucene` the query become `+((cs_contents:canal cs_contents:canal) (cs_docs:canal cs_docs:canal) (cs_annots:canal cs_annots:canal)) +DBName:dPortal +TableName:CASE_ACTION`

even if i escape the plus with backslash it doesn't work cause the backslash is a special character in this library too.

Answer (score 0):

Then I suggest that you try escaping backslash as well: \\+

Comment: thank you for ur fast reply, i tried using double backslash and it is still not working...any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write your literal in quotes like this.

```
cs_contents:"(canal+)" OR cs_docs:"(canal+)" OR cs_annots:"(canal+)"
```

Comment: thank you for ur fast reply, i tried using quotes also and it is still not working...any other ideas?

Comment: See these [Lucene Docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html), I have some question regarding this. why you have included brackets? Why you kept this + sign? All are these literal or are operators?

Comment: the plus sign here is not an operator, it is included in the search cirteria and this is why it affects my search results by disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Double backslash might do the trick (that's how `org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.QueryParserUtil` does it), **but this will work if and only if** the `+` is in the field *index*!

If you **tokenized** the field during indexing the `+` character is not likely to be a part of the indexed value, and if you are using the same tokenizing analyzer at query parsing you're not going to search to the `+` either, regardless of escaping (query string is passed via analyzer).

One workaround for that is not to tokenize fields with relevant special chars - and use a non-tokenizing analyzer (e.g. a `KeywordAnalyzer`) at query parsing - if you can distinguish the queries with special chars from the ones without...

Usually the values used by Lucene (in index, in queries) are NOT the exact values passed to lucene, e.g. usually all strings are lowercased (self-explanatory) and tokenized (split into words, stripped of special characters). This depends on Analyzer used, field types, etc.

**Indexing**:

```
Analyzer(field value) = value stored in index
```

**Query time**:

```
QueryParser(Analyzer(query string)) = query passed to Lucene
```

Comment: thank you for ur fast reply, i tried using double backslash and it is still not working...any other ideas?

Comment: I agree with Jan - Standard Tokenizer shall eliminate + from tokenized and saved characters and therefore you most probably do not have it in index.

Answer (score 0):

The [`QueryParser` documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html) explains what should be escaped. The programmatic way to perform such escaping is using [`QueryParserBase.escape(String)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape(java.lang.String)).